# Perl, string replacement

Tags: string, perl

I want to convert each letter in a sentence to a certain letter depending on if it is a consonant or a vowel, where vowels are AEIOU.

So if I have a string

```
$string = 'Hello'
```

I would like to see

```
$string = 'CVCCV'
```

As a result.

I know I can use:

```
$string =~ s/A/V/
$string =~ s/B/C/
$string =~ s/C/C/
```

and so on to check and convert each letter individually, but surely there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use... `s/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/C/gi` and `s/[aeiou]/V/gi`. These are called [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).  The `i` flag makes the match case-insensitive.

Comment: No problem. http://www.regular-expressions.info is an excellent reference; you might find it useful.

Comment: There’s always `y/AEIOU/V/`, although I suspect that its complement, `y/AEIOU/C/c`, might not be what you were exactly looking for. If you’re really going to use `s///`, you might as well use the case-insensitive `/i`, eh?

Comment: Did you try this? the 2nd s/// will replace the "V" from the 1st one with "C"s, you'll end up with a string that is *all* "C"s...

Comment: Hah, yeah, you're right.  You can solve the problem by just using them in the other order.

Comment: The transliteration operator (tr///) is the right tool for this, not the substitution operator (s///). See tadmc's answer.

Comment: Enumerating consonants is less readable than enumerating vowels, because it is too hard to verify that you haven’t missed one.  On a different issue, you can’t really call Y a consonant by any reasonable definition.

Answer (score 19):

normalize case, then apply the transliteration operator:

```
$string = lc $string;
$string =~ tr/aeioua-z/VVVVVC/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/([aeiou])|[a-z]/ defined $1 ? 'V' : 'C' /ieg
```